# Batch Script + FFmpeg -- Use FOR loop to pipe AND concat all files found except last file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, ffmpeg, pipe

Im trying to convert all '.mp4' files in a folder into '.ts' files so I can use FFmpeg.exe to combine them all into one long '.mp4' video.

I have to use the `concat` command to combine the .ts files when using ffmpeg.

Below is a working line of code to do this the long way.... I want to use a for loop in case I have way more than just 3 files to combine.

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -y -i concat:"a.ts|b.ts|c.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "COMBINED.mp4"
```

I can make this loop work by using the below `for command` but the last file found can not have a pipe after it `|` like `c.ts"` above didn't.

```
    FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=* DELIMS= ,|" %%I IN ('%%~dpnG.ts') DO (
    SET FNAME=%%~dpnI
    ECHO.
    ECHO !FNAME!
    PAUSE>NUL
    EXIT
)
```

Does anyone know if it's even possible (maybe with tokens) to do this in a batch file? If not any suggestions? PowerShell?

In response to Compo's question here is my working script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
COLOR 0A
TITLE CONCAT MULTIPLE MP4 FILES

PUSHD "%~dp0"

SET FF="C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe"

:: SET VIDEO NAME WITHOUT EXTENSION (.MP4)
SET IN01=a
SET IN02=b
SET IN03=c
SET COMBINED=FULL

:: CREATE TEMP .TS VIDEOS OF THE FILES YOU WANT TO COMBINE
%FF% -hide_banner -y -i "%IN01%.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "%IN01%.ts"
%FF% -hide_banner -y -i "%IN02%.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "%IN02%.ts"
%FF% -hide_banner -y -i "%IN03%.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "%IN03%.ts"

:: COMBINE TEMP .TS FILES INTO COMBINED .MP4
%FF% -hide_banner -y -i concat:"%IN01%.ts|%IN02%.ts|%IN03%.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "%COMBINED%.mp4"

ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: Is your question how do I get each `.ts` file in a specific location, and place them into a useable string delimited with a specific character?

Comment: My question is how do I pipe the defined variables at the top to the concat AKA pipe using a for command. I'm sorry I wasn't able to say that the first time.

Comment: Your question to me, regardless of your comment above is related to not wanting to hard code three variables for each of your `.ts` files, because there may be a different number of them, and you'd prefer something which programatically gets all of them and creates, either a single variable holding all of them, each delimited with a pipe character; or each as a separate variable which you could yourself separate with pipe characters. Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: That is a correct way to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example script which, based upon my understanding, should do as you needed:

```bsh
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
COLOR 0A
TITLE CONCAT MULTIPLE MP4 FILES

SET "FF=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe"
SET "COMBINEDBASENAME=FULL"
SET "CONCATLIST="

PUSHD "%~dp0"

FOR %%G IN (*.mp4) DO (
    REM CREATE TEMP .TS VIDEOS OF THE FILES YOU WANT TO COMBINE
    "%FF%" -hide_banner -y -i "%%~G" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "%%~nG.ts"
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF EXIST "%%~nG.ts" (
        IF NOT DEFINED CONCATLIST (SET "CONCATLIST=%%~nG.ts") ELSE (
            SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
            FOR %%H In ("!CONCATLIST!|%%~nG.ts") DO ENDLOCAL & SET "CONCATLIST=%%~H"
        )
    )
)

IF NOT DEFINED CONCATLIST GOTO :EOF

REM COMBINE TEMP .TS FILES INTO COMBINED .MP4
"%FF%" -hide_banner -y -i concat:"%CONCATLIST%" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "%COMBINEDBASENAME%.mp4"

REM REMOVE :: FROM THE NEXT LINE TO DELETE THE .TS FILES
::DEL "%CONCATLIST:|=" "%"

ECHO=
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```